# jsoup : parse data of p tag which is between every h2 tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse certain information through jsoup in Java from last 3 days -_-, this is my code:

```
   Document document = Jsoup.connect(urlofpage).get();
        Elements links = document.select(".contentBox");
         for (Element link : links) {
                 // String name = link.text();
                 String title = link.select("h2").text();
                 int h2length = link.select("h2").size();  

                 for( int i = 0; i <= h2length -1; i++)
                 {
                 String s = link.select("h2").get(i).text();
                  boolean desc1 = Pattern.compile("What is").matcher(s).find(); 
                  boolean desc2 = Pattern.compile("Uses for").matcher(s).find();

                if(desc1 == true || desc2 == true)
                    { 
                        String descritop = "";
                        int plength = link.select("p ~ h2 ~ p").size() - link.select("h2 ~ p").size();   
                        System.out.println(h2length); 
                        String ssv = link.select("h2 ~ p").get(1).text(); 
                     }
                 }
```

It is fetching the data as it is directed, fetching the data of h2 and p separated, but the problem is, I want to parse the d`ata inside of <p> tag which is just after every <h2> tag`.

For example (HTML content):

```
<h2>main content</h2>
<div class="acx"><div>
<p>content</p>
<p>content 2</p>

<h2>content 2</h2>
<div class="acx"><div>
<p>new content od 2</p>
<p>new 2</p>
```

Now it should fetch like (in array):

```
array[0] = "content content 2",
array[1] = "new content od 2 new 2",
```

Any solutions?

URL for parsing is https://www.drugs.com/mtm/a-d-topical.html

Answer (score 1):

My idea is simple. Get first `p` Element after `h2` element and it to the ArrayList, then check if the next element is p and add it too. As example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> textInsidePList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for (Element link : links) {
    Elements headings2 = link.select("h2 ~ p");
    for (int i = 0; i < headings2.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> textInsideP = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        textInsideP.add(headings2.get(i).text());
        Element nextPar = headings2.get(i).nextElementSibling();
        if (nextPar.nodeName() == "p") {
            textInsideP.add(nextPar.text());
        }
        textInsidePList.add(textInsideP);
    }
}
```

If you have more then 2 `p` Element, you simply need to write a recursion. But this code will not work if you can have other element between `p`'s. As a result you will have an ArrayList, containing an ArrayLists that represent `h2` element with text from `p` Nodes.

**Edit**. Example with recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String html = "<h2>first h2</h2>" +
                "<div class=\"acx\"></div>" +
                "<p>first h2 content 1</p>" +
                "<p>first h2 content 2</p>" +
                "<p>first h2 content 3</p>" +
                "<p>first h2 content 4</p>" +
                "<h2>second h2</h2>" +
                "<div class=\"acx\"></div>" +
                "<p>second h2 content 1</p>" +
                "<p>second h2 content 2</p>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

        /* creating first order ArrayList */
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> textInsidePList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        Elements headings2 = document.select("h2");
        for (Element heading2 : headings2) {
            /* creating second order ArrayList and adding data */

            ArrayList<String> textInsideP = new ArrayList<String>();
            textInsideP.add(heading2.text()); // delete this line to remove h2 content from array, this just for example
            parsingRecursion(heading2, textInsideP);
            textInsidePList.add(textInsideP);

        }

        /* iteraiting through ArrayList */
        for (ArrayList<String> firstH2 : textInsidePList) {
            System.out.println("h2:");
            for (String parsInsideH2 : firstH2) {
                System.out.println(parsInsideH2);
            }
        }

    }

    /* recursive function */
    private static void parsingRecursion(Element heading2, ArrayList<String> textInsideP) {
        Element nextPar = heading2.nextElementSibling();
        if (nextPar != null && nextPar.nodeName() == "p") {
            textInsideP.add(nextPar.text());
            parsingRecursion(nextPar, textInsideP);
        } else if (nextPar != null && nextPar.nodeName() != "h2") {
            Element nextNotP = nextPar.nextElementSibling();
            textInsideP.add(nextNotP.text());
            parsingRecursion(nextNotP, textInsideP);
        }
    }
}
```

output in console:

```
    h2:
    first h2
    first h2 content 1
    first h2 content 2
    first h2 content 3
    first h2 content 4
    h2:
    second h2
    second h2 content 1
    second h2 content 2
```

Recursion was used because we don't know how many 'p' nodes will we meet before `h2`. ArrayList was used instead of an array because we can add elements there dynamically without setting up the size of an array.

**Edit #2**, as the question has changed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(pathToYoursCusromUrl).get();
        Elements links = document.select(".contentBox");
        for (Element link : links) {
        /* creating first order ArrayList */
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> textInsidePList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            Elements headings2 = document.select("h2");
            for (Element heading2 : headings2) {
            /* creating second order ArrayList and adding data */

                ArrayList<String> textInsideP = new ArrayList<String>();
                parsingRecursion(heading2, textInsideP);
                textInsidePList.add(textInsideP);

            }

        /* iteraiting through ArrayList */
            for (ArrayList<String> firstH2 : textInsidePList) {
                System.out.println("h2:");
                for (String parsInsideH2 : firstH2) {
                    System.out.println("p:" + parsInsideH2);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /* recursive function */
    private static void parsingRecursion(Element heading2, ArrayList<String> textInsideP) {
        Element nextPar = heading2.nextElementSibling();
        if (nextPar != null && nextPar.nodeName() == "p") {
            textInsideP.add(nextPar.text());
            parsingRecursion(nextPar, textInsideP);
        } else if (nextPar != null && nextPar.nodeName() != "h2") {
            Element nextNotP = nextPar.nextElementSibling();
            if (nextNotP != null) {
                textInsideP.add(nextNotP.text());
                parsingRecursion(nextNotP, textInsideP);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

output in console:

```
h2:
p:Vitamins A, D, and E topical (for the skin) is a skin protectant. It works by moisturizing and sealing the skin, and aids in skin healing.
p:This medication is used to treat diaper rash, dry or chafed skin, and minor cuts or burns.
p:Vitamins A, D, and E may also be used for purposes not listed in this medication guide.
h2:
p:You should not use this medication if your child is allergic to it. Do not apply vitamins A, D, and E topical without a rubber glove or finger cot if you are allergic this medication.
p:Ask a doctor or pharmacist if it is safe for you to use this medication on your child if the child is allergic to any medicines or skin products, including soaps, oils, lotions, or creams.
p:Stop using the medication and call your doctor at once if your child has a serious side effect such as warmth, redness, oozing, or severe irritation where the medicine is applied.
p:Keep the baby's diaper area as dry as possible. Change wet or soiled diapers immediately to keep wetness and bacteria from irritating the baby's skin. Always put on a new diaper when the baby first wakes up in the morning, and also just before putting the baby to bed each night.
```

and so on...

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer : but some problem here when you write  `Elements headings2 = link.select("h2 ~ p");` it will get all the <p> tag elements in the page so for loop will simple add all the <p> tag data into one array it wont fetch the the data of <p> between two tag of <h2>

Comment: but thanks for the answer , i think nextElementSibling();will solve my question

Comment: Hmm, really? It must create new ArrayList on each new Node `p` after `h2`: `ArrayList<String> textInsideP = new ArrayList<String>(); `. Maybe I don't really know Jsoup selectors...

Comment: yes you are correct with your undestanding it will selecting the p node after h2 but... it have to be stop when next h2 will come and then repeat the same again :)

Comment: It creates new ArrayList on each Node `p` after `h2`.  this part of code `textInsidePList.add(textInsideP);` appends this ArrayList in to the another ArrayList. And when we have not `p` new ArrayList is created. So we have ArrayLists inside ArrayList of ArrayLists Can you confirm that you tried the code and all `p` was in one ArrayList inside ArrayList?

Comment: I want to find where I am mistaken :)

Comment: in simple words `Element nextPar = headings2.get(i).nextElementSibling();` this line will always be 0 for p.. i want to make it P = 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 till next h2 tag wont come

Comment: Ok. Maybe we just didn't understand each other. Just laid my hands on IDE. I have added the example with recursion. Tested with real input. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes.. this is what i wanted.. + i have made my own algo but i must say this one is better than mine...except.. one exception if there will be no p  left then and when it will go at 'textInsideP.add(nextNotP.text());' line it will cause null pointer excetption [in else if conditional ]

Comment: Do you confirm, that you have tested this code and got nullpointerexception? or you simply try to guess like the first time:) I have already tested it and all worked fine! According to the code, it will find all `p` nodes, which  are siblings to `h2` node. If all siblings are checked or there is `h2` node, the code returns to for loop. If there is no next sibling recursion stops! Please read the code more carefully ;)

Comment: i have not tested the code when i commented but when you asked it i tested the code in ide and it gives me the exact error..
`Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.drugs.com/mtm/a-d-topical.html").get();
    Elements headings2 = document.select("h2");`

for your refrenece use this line for actual environment and it will give you null pointer

Comment: OK. But I worked with your html example. You should explicitly post your examples here. not put a link to other sites. I have modified the code according to the site you parse.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  i think u didnt read my question carefully at the bottom of the ques i already shared the html data url from where i am parsing also i beleive code should run at any similar condition + in the question i said 1 array should consist multiple lines of <p> it means it will be in string it means one h2 tag will have one array consist of multiple data of p in strings like h[0] = p + p + p the when next h2 come then it will be like h[1] = p + p +p (p is the next sibling of the particular h2 tag).. i hope u r not finding it in a negative way